# What is the SQLite command for getting the data between a start and end time?

Tags: database, sqlite, strftime

Let's say my database is called "data" and its second column is called "datetime". The format of my datetime is "7/22/2011 12:00:00". If I want to get the the information between 12:00 and 13:00 today, how do I do that?

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE 
strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', datetime) > strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', '7/22/2011 12:00:00') 
AND 
strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', datetime) < strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', '7/22/2011 13:00:00')
```

doesn't do the trick.

Comment: are you using an application language in addition to sqlite?  say, python, ruby or java?

Comment: I'm just wondering about the raw query. I'm using Java, and I'll surround that query with data.rawQuery(whateverTheQueryIs, null);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this wrong -- shame on me. `strftime` will only read in ISO 8601 (or timestamp/julian) values. **The format specified doesn't apply to the the *input* -- it is only for the *output* value.**

For this reason the data *in* the database must still have a natural ordering to be sorted. The suggested formats are ISO 8601 (string), timestamp (integer), and julian-date (float). Using a date like `m/d/y` in the database *won't work* for range compares because it fails to adhere to natural ordering.

`strftime` and friends simply allow generation of one of the values useful for the comparison -- e.g. can convert from *ISO 8601/timestamp/julian* input to *custom/ISO 8601/timestamp/julian-date*. They can not directly convert *from* a custom value though.

The easiest way to fix the database is probably to use a language like Python to write a script for the conversion of existing data. A small Java program could also be written taking advantage of [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse the existing values and write them back using one of the recommended types.

---

Historical:

*Try it in pieces from the console* (this will enable *must faster* experimenting with the query) -- the first conditional then the second. What returns what and why? Once each piece is working then putting them to-gether will work.

**There are multiple strftime format mistakes** -- see [Date and Time](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for the formats and check the strings again :) Also, if using a saner date format (ISO 8601), could just use `datetime` and not worry about specifying the format explicitly. ISO 8601 values are is also lexically sortable as strings -- an added advantage.

I am not sure how the Java SQLite adatper will handle a Date when passed as a *parameter* to a parametrized query (parametrized queries *really should* be used) ... but in any case this is a secondary issue to the current behavior observed.

Happy coding.

Comment: My months are "7" instead of "07". Could that be the problem? I really can't go through and edit my file though, since it has 66,000 rows.

Comment: @TheBeatlemaniac I have forgotten my sqlite bad :( See the updated answer. Use a script (say python) to turn the data in the database into ISO 8601 or similar. I forget that `strftime` is not about converting from, but converting to.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you've got a bad format character

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE 
strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%H:%S', datetime) > strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S', '7/22/2011 12:00:00') 
--                     ^ 
AND 
strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S', datetime) < strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S', '7/22/2011 13:00:00')
```